# Mac Mini won't start, shuts down on startup chord

Tags: mac-mini

My Mac Mini bought early 2013 won't start. I get half the Apple startup chord and then it shuts down again. It doesn't even get to the gray screen, apparently no video output. I tried the different keyboard commands and also pulling out all cables to see if there is any external devices that is the cause but no luck. Reading from a suggetion I also held down the power button for 20 seconds after pulling out the power cord. But the problem remain. After pressing power I hear the sound coming and then goes out after less than a second.

Is there anything I can try except taking it to the Apple repair guys?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added/changed any of the internal hardware at some point?

If your Mac Mini has more than one RAM-block, you could try booting it up with only one block inserted (if it doesn't work with the first block, try with only the second block). That could eliminate faulty RAM as the cause.

The problem is most likely hardware related, and could be for example a defective power supply.

Comment: Thanks. Well, when the device was new I replace the internal HDD with a SSD drive. Other than that there have been no change or opening of the computer. I will check the RAM's as you suggest, but as you say it will probably end up with a service...